# Wait while the console still has information to print

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

While developing an Eclipse plug-in, I want to output some paths in the console and then add some hyperlinks to those paths.

Instead of parsing the console, I thought about calculating the hyperlinks locations by the string which holds the path length which I print in console.

The problem which I have is that I try to create the `hyperlink`, but the information isn't printed yet in the console, therefore I get random bad location exceptions. It works if I run it in debug mode and I have a breakpoint on the hyperlink creation loop.

I tried to separate the creation of hyperlinks and wait until the `messageQueue` is empty, but that didn't work out.

```java
private BlockingQueue<String> messageQueue = Queues.newLinkedBlockingQueue()
for ( String message : messages) {
    messageQueue.offer(message);
    // here I create a new HyperLinkInformation object and put it in a list
}

// wait until the queue is empty
while(!messageQueue.isEmpty()) {}

for (HyperLink hyperLinkObj : hyperlinkInformations) {
    // try to create the hyperlink
}
```

Any ideas on how I could check if the console still has something to print?

Comment: The usual way to modify things in a console is by using one of the console listener extension points such as `org.eclipse.ui.console.consolePatternMatchListeners`

Comment: @greg-449 Thank you, I'll look forward to it and read the docs

Comment: @greg-449 Looks a good solution if the data printed is random and you want to catch some patterns, but I do not see the point to output the information which I already have in memory to the console, then to add a pattern to get the information which I already have to create hyperlinks.